C++ JNI:Error occurred during initialization of VMFailed setting boot class path
First run main.exe it said can not find jvm.dll

So I copy jvm.dll from C:\Program Files\Zulu\zulu-21\bin\server to ./
Then this is my workspace.
ls
jvm.dll   main.cpp  main.exe  main.obj

But second run it said
Error occurred during initialization of VM
Failed setting boot class path.

It still can't work with jvm.dll.
This is my code
#include <jni.h> /* where everything is defined */

int main()
{
    JavaVM* jvm; /* denotes a Java VM */
    JNIEnv* env; /* pointer to native method interface */
    JavaVMInitArgs vm_args; /* JDK/JRE 19 VM initialization arguments */
    JavaVMOption* options = new JavaVMOption[1];
    options[0].optionString = "-Djava.class.path=C:\\Program Files\\Zulu\\zulu-21\\lib";
    vm_args.version = JNI_VERSION_19;
    vm_args.nOptions = 1;
    vm_args.options = options;
    vm_args.ignoreUnrecognized = false;
    /* load and initialize a Java VM, return a JNI interface
     * pointer in env */
    JNI_CreateJavaVM(&jvm, (void**)&env, &vm_args);
    delete options;
    /* We are done. */
    jvm->DestroyJavaVM();
}

This is my build task:
 cl.exe C:\Users\AB\Desktop\tmp\whylinkerr\main.cpp /I "C:\Program Files\Zulu\zulu-21\include" /I "C:\Program Files\Zulu\zulu-21\include\win32" /link "C:\Program Files\Zulu\zulu-21\lib\jvm.lib"

I tried     options[0].optionString = "-Xbootclasspath/a:C:\\Program Files\\Zulu\\zulu-21;";
But it still say Failed setting boot class path.
My code was copied from the official website https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/specs/jni/invocation.html

Unless that lib directory contains an exploded tree of class files, you will need to set the classpath to C:\Program Files\Zulu\zulu-21\lib\* instead so it will load all jars. Better still, drop the argument entirely since that's the default...

Update
Do not need jvm.dll in workspace. All I have to do is edit Path.
$env:path = "C:\Program Files\Zulu\zulu-21\bin\server;$env:Path"


I find another solution. Just rm jvm.dll in workspace,
then

typedef int (__stdcall * JNI_CreateJavaVMFunc)(JavaVM** pvm, JNIEnv** penv, void* args);

HINSTANCE jvmDLL = LoadLibraryA("C:\\Program Files\\Zulu\\zulu-21\\bin\\server\\jvm.dll");

JNI_CreateJavaVMFunc Dll_JNI_CreateJavaVM = (JNI_CreateJavaVMFunc)GetProcAddress(jvmDLL, "JNI_CreateJavaVM");
JavaVM* jvm = nullptr;
JNIEnv* env = nullptr;
JavaVMInitArgs vm_args; /* JDK/JRE 19 VM initialization arguments */
JavaVMOption* options = new JavaVMOption[1];
char arg[50] = "-verbose:jni";
options[0].optionString = arg;
vm_args.version = JNI_VERSION_1_8;
vm_args.nOptions = 1;
vm_args.options = options;
vm_args.ignoreUnrecognized = true;

auto check = Dll_JNI_CreateJavaVM(&jvm, & env, &vm_args);

Then everything works fine...
Do not use JNI_CreateJavaVM in jni.h
I found this solution from jni-sys

So at the end of the day you were picking up a different libjvm.dll than the one you intended. Doh.

I found that I was missing a lot of details in my questions. Now I have added them. I also updated the answers to show my new solution. @Botje
